# How do you query the database within the model?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

**NOTE:** This is an entire rewrite of the previous question.

I have a model.

```
class Paragraph
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int SectionId { get; set; }
    public virtual Section Section { get; set; }

    public int Major { get; set; }
    public int Option { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Paragraph> Options
    {
        get
        {
            // What I'm trying to return is:
            //
            //     Section.Paragraphs
            //     .Where(p => p.Major == Major && p.Option != Option)
            //     .ToList()
        }
    }
}
```

It is involved in a `one to many` relationship; where each `Section` has many `Paragraphs`.  What I'm trying to return is a list of paragraphs where their `Major` is the same as the entity's `Major` and the `Option` isn't the same.  Basically.

```
Where(p => p.Major == Major && p.Option != Option)
```

Any advice on how to accomplish this?  Thank you.

Comment: Need more code. How are you setting Section in the Options collection? No way to help here without the context of what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: What do you mean setting `Section` in the `Options` collection?

Comment: Per your update, what do you mean it "didn't work"?

Comment: I got the same error as before, that `Section` is null.

Comment: Does DocumentDb.Sections contain sections at all? If so, I wonder if sectionId points to the correct table.

Comment: Yes.  `DocumentDb.Sections` contains three sections.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it.  Woop-woop!  All I did was check if `Section` was null, and if it was I returned a blank `List<Paragraph>`.  So `Options` becomes.

```
    public ICollection<Paragraph> Options
    {
        get
        {
            if (Section != null)
            {
                return Section.Paragraphs
                    .Where(p => p.Major == Major && p.Option != Option)
                    .ToList();
            }
            else
            {
                return new List<Paragraph>();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You want your `Section` property to be non-null.  Presumably you have a `Section` class that has a property of type `List<Paragraph>` or the like, since you describe this situation as one model "belonging" to another.

If you are thinking that just because your paragraph is contained in a section, you will get some sort of reciprocity for free, you are mistaken.  You will have to see to maintaining this relationship yourself.

Comment: Okay.  How would I go about do this though?

Comment: Show us the code where you are adding paragraphs to sections.  That would probably be the logical place.

Comment: There is a one-to-many relationship between a `Section` and the `Paragraphs`.  I'm currently using an initializer to populate the data that is automatically taken care of by MVC.

Comment: Are you using an ORM?  (l2s, entity framework, etc.)  ORMs tend to see to handling this sort of thing, but if you're rolling it on your own, you'll have to set the `Section` property at the point where you are adding the paragraph to the section.   I'm not sure what you mean by "I'm currently using an initializer to populate the data...".

Comment: I'm using Entity Framework and an initializer in Entity basically populates the database every time the application is built.

Comment: Ok, but your model class (`Paragraph`) -- is that an entity framework class?  Or a model class for MVC?

Comment: `Paragraph` is an Entity model.